# adding column with the length of other column as value using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have task to calculate each column length and add message to "errorMsg" column. I am able to filter the record based on length but not able to append message in new column.

eg.
I want find out only invalid records with message on new column "ErrorMsg"

recordlength=4

```
InputDataFrame-             
+------+
| value|
+------+
|Pra   |
|Akshay|
|  Raju|
|Shakti|
|xyz   |
+------+
```

OutputDataFrame

```
+------+------------------------+
| value|ErrorMsg                |
+------+------------------------+
|Pra   |Less Than total Length
|Akshay|Greater than total length 
|Shakti|Greater than total length
|xyx   |Less than total length
+------+-------------------------
```

Where raju is my true record it goes to valid records without message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would get the desired result.

```
val df = Seq("Pra", "Akshay", "Raju", "Shakti", "xyz").toDF("value")
df
 .filter(not(length($"value") === 4))
 .withColumn("ErrorMsg", when(length($"value") > lit(4), "Greater than total length").otherwise("Less Than total Length"))
 .show(10000, false)

+------+-------------------------+
|value |ErrorMsg                 |
+------+-------------------------+
|Pra   |Less Than total Length   |
|Akshay|Greater than total length|
|Shakti|Greater than total length|
|xyz   |Less Than total Length   |
+------+-------------------------+
```